# Magento 2 - what full page caching software should I use if I plan to use HTTPS?

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache, https, varnish

I have been reading the documentation for using Varnish on my magento website but I plan to use HTTPS both on front-end and on the back-end.
According to the documentation pages, Varnish cannot be used with HTTPS, probably because the pages get encrypted before being passed to varnish for caching, and I'd like to know if there's anything I use to perform full-page caching with HTTPS on the front end.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you're not referring to Magento 2. For Magento 1.x, you can use [Turpentine](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine) to let Magento work with Varnish. Fair warning, this is by no means a "plug and play" process!

Varnish does *not* terminate SSL connections, so you're correct that it won't work by itself for HTTPS. You can however use something like nginx or pound to handle the terminate part - which then passes the request on to Varnish for processing. There's lots of guides out there to help you set this up - it's very dependent on your server environment so it's hard to give very specific recommendations.

Here is one of many tutorials including using nginx for ssl termination: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-varnish-cache-4-0-with-ssl-termination-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I was indeed referring to Magento 2. Thank you very much for your answer.  How easier/harder is it to perform the setup you described in Apache? Any recommended reading for Apache setup?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: https://github.com/magespecialist/lts2 .

It is an internal FPC cache for Magento. Working with HTTPS too without problems.
Compatible from 1.7.x to 1.9.x